# Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in .NET Framework 4.7.1 project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, nuget, odata, .net-standard

I'm attempting to install the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection and Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions 2.0.0 nuget packages into a .NET Framework 4.7.1 project (Microsoft.AspNet.OData), however I'm getting the error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
>   2.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1', but the package does not
>   contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible
>   with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

The dependency for these packages is .NETStandard,Version=v2.0. I understand that .NET Standard isn't .NET Framework, however I thought that .NET Framework 4.6 and greater projects could install .NET Standard projects? If this isn't possible, then are there other equivalent versions of these nuget packages for .NET Framework?

The whole reason that I'm going through this exercise is because many developers are completely blocked by Microsoft.AspNet.OData only supporting DI 1.0, not 2.0. This means that we cannot upgrade our nuget packages in our OData web api, as other packages require DI 2.0 but OData is stuck on 1.0. The rest of our applications are using the latest and greatest, so really it means that our OData web api solution can't leverage ANY of our shared code, and is completely quarantined until this compatibility block is resolved.

Answer (score 2):

> Installing Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection in .NET Framework 4.7.1 project

I think the error message is not accurate. When I install the nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.0.0` to the project (`Microsoft.AspNet.OData`), I got the following error message:

> Unable to resolve dependencies.
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.0.0' is not compatible
>   with 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData 7.0.0-beta2 constraint:
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (>= 1.0.0 && < 2.0.0)'.

That is exactly what you said "*because many developers are completely blocked by Microsoft.AspNet.OData only supporting DI 1.0, not 2.0.*"

Check the dependencies of package `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`, we could know there are strict restrictions for the dependencies `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection` and `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions` (`(>= 1.0.0 && < 2.0.0)`)

So, this is really a issue that the package `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` don't support DI 2.0. Many other communities also report this issue on [Github](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1119), but there is still no any workaround and solution.

My current **workaround** is:

- Create a new project without installing package `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`.
- Install the other dependencies of package `Microsoft.AspNet.OData`: `Microsoft.OData.Core (>= 7.2.0 && < 8.0.0)`, `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core (>= 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client (>= 5.2.2 && < 5.3.0)` (The latter two packages should be included in the template by default).
- Install the nuget package `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection 2.0.0`
- Install the nuget package `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` with option `-IgnoreDependencies` in the Package Manager Console:

  update-package Microsoft.AspNet.OData -IgnoreDependencies -IncludePrerelease

With this workaround, we could use `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` and DI 2.0, but I could fully confirm whether breaking the dependency limition will cause any problem for the `Microsoft.AspNet.OData` package. Simple tests are not problematic.

Hope this helps.